# Python: How to find the average on each array in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist, average

Lets say I have a list with three arrays as following:

`[(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]`

Is it possible I get the average by diving each "slot" of the arrays in the list.
For example:

`(1+2+2)/3, (2+0+9)/3, (0+6+6)/3`

and make it become new arraylist with only 3 integers.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? The [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) functions make this pretty easy.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry for my poor explaination.The `sum` and `len` function are easy to find out the average of each array in the list. But what I want is the the average of  each slot of the arrays. For instant, `average of all array(0), array(1) and, array(2)`. I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Oops, that's my fault, I should have read more carefully.  You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to associate all of the elements in each of the interior tuples by index

```
tups = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
print([sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*tups)])
# [1.6666666666666667, 4.666666666666667, 4.0]
```

You can also do something like `sum(x)//len(x)` or `round(sum(x)/len(x))` inside the list comprehension to get an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways you can do it.

```
data = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
avg_array = []
for tu in data:
    avg_array.append(sum(tu)/len(tu))
print(avg_array)
```

using list comprehension

```
data = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
comp = [ sum(i)/len(i) for i in data]
print(comp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by doing something like this.

Create an empty array. Loop through your current array and use the sum and len functions to calculate averages. Then append the average to your new array.

```
array = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
arraynew = []

for i in range(0,len(array)):
    arraynew.append(sum(array[i]) / len(array[i]))

print arraynew
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable :(

Comment: The code is working fine for me using Python v2.7.13 and in v3.6.2 aswell.

Answer (score 0):

As you were told in the comments with `sum` and `len` it's pretty easy.

But in python I would do something like this, assuming you want to maintain decimal precision:

```
list = [(1, 2, 0), (2, 9, 6), (2, 3, 6)]
res = map(lambda l: round(float(sum(l)) / len(l), 2), list)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 5.67, 3.67]
```

But as you said you wanted 3 `int`s in your question, would be like this:

```
res = map(lambda l: sum(l) / len(l), list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 3]
```

Edit:

To sum the same index of each tuple, the most elegant method is the solution provided by @PatrickHaugh.

On the other hand, if you are not fond of list comprehensions and some built in functions as `zip` is, here's a little longer and less elegant version using a `for` loop:

```
arr = []
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    arr.append(sum(l[i] for l in list) / len(list))
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my poor explanation.  My intention is to get the the average of each slot of the arrays. For instant, average of all array(0), array(1) and, array(2). I hope this is understandable

Comment: @Icc I don't know if I understood your demand correctly, but I guessed you are interpreting each tuple `(1, 2, 0)` as an array that must be averaged. Or are you asking the average of the first position of every tuple like `(1, 2, 0) => 1 / (2, 9, 6) => 2` and so on?

Comment: `(1,2,2), (2,9,3), (0,6,6)` instead.